# Is there an elementary abelian subgroup $H$ s.t. every involution $\sigma$ is conjugated to an element in $H$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Is there an elementary abelian $2$-subgroup $H$ of $G$, i.e. $H\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$, such that every involution of $G$ is conjugated to an element in $H$?

I.e. for every $\sigma \in G$ with $\sigma^2=1$, there is $h\in H$ and $\tau \in G$ s.t. $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}= h$.

The question is motivated by the following idea: Start with $H_1=\langle \sigma_1 \rangle$ for some involution $\sigma_1\in H$. Let $\sigma_2\in G$ be another involution of $G$, than either $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ commute (set $H_2=\langle \sigma_1,\sigma_2 \rangle$ in this case) or are conjugated by another involution $\sigma_2'$ that commutes with $\sigma_1$ (set $H_2=\langle \sigma_1,\sigma_2' \rangle$ in this case). But I am not sure how to continue this construction in order to get $H_3,\dots$

I would be happy about a counter example or a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dihedral group of order $8$ (or of order $2^n$ for any $n \ge 3$) is a counterexample.